# Labeling parts of 3D model with Android and OpenGL ES/Rajawali

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, rajawali

I have imported a model (e.g. a teapot) using Rajawali into my scene.
What I would like is to label parts of the model (e.g. the lid, body, foot, handle and the spout)
using plain Android views, but I have no idea how this could be achieved. Specifically, positioning
the labels on the right place seems challenging. The idea is that when I transform my model's position in the scene, the tips of the labels are still correctly positioned

Rajawali tutorial show how Android views can be placed on top of the scene here https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/wiki/Tutorial-08-Adding-User-Interface-Elements
. I also understand how using the transformation matrices a 3D coordinate on the model can be
transformed into a 2D coordinate on the screen, but I have no idea how to determine the exact 3D coordinates
on the model itself. The model is exported to OBJ format using Blender, so I assume there is some clever way of determining
the coordinates in Blender and exporting them to a separate file or include them somehow in the OBJ file (but not
render those points, only include them as metadata), but I have no idea how I could do that.

Any ideas are very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a screenquad, not a view. This is a general GL solution, and will also work with iOS.

You must determine the indices of the desired model vertices. Using the text rendering algo below, you can just fiddle them until you hit the right ones.

1. Create a reasonable ARGB bitmap with same aspect ratio as the screen.
2. Create the screenquad texture using this bitmap
3. Create a canvas using this bitmap
4. The rest happens in onDrawFrame(). Clear the canvas using clear paint.
5. Use the MVP matrix to convert desired model vertices to canvas coordinates.
6. Draw your desired text at the canvas coordinates
7. Update the texture.

---

- Your text will render very precisely at the vertices you specfied. The GL thread will double-buffer and loop you back to #4. Super smooth 3D text animation!
- Use double floating point math to avoid loss of precision during coordinate conversion, which results in wobbly text. You could even use the z value of the vertex to scale the text. Fancy!
- The performance bottleneck is #7 since the entire bitmap must be copied to GL texture memory, every frame. Try to keep the bitmap as small as possible, maintaining aspect ratio. Maybe let the user toggle the labels.
- Note that the copy to GL texture memory is redundant since in OpenGL-ES, GL memory is just regular memory. For compatibility reasons, a redundant chunk of regular memory is reserved to artificially enforce the copy.

Comment: Thanks Dominik for the answer. However, I am still left unsure on how to map the coordinates. As for drawing on the canvas, I am not sure if then I could have any user interactivity with the labels. I wanted to use views because I need the labels to be responsive to tap events.

Comment: Use the MVPMatrix (model-view-projection) provided by the material class to convert 3d to screen coords. Since onTouch events give screen coords, you do not need Views for anything. Views are handled on a separate UI thread, and syncing the UI thread to the GL thread is extremely problematic. Just use the GL thread.

Comment: BTW you could also use a GL_POINTS particle system with VBO, FBO and texture altas backing for very fast rendering of labels. Note that a pure GL solution is portable to iOS, Win10, WebGL, etc

Comment: Alright, thanks! In the meantime, I worked out the UI thread solution, it actually works like a charm on my HTC One. Why do you say it's extremely problematic to sync those threads?

Comment: It is problematic to share data between any independently synchronized threads. If you never plan to share any data between UI and GL threads, then there is no problem. Also, you will notice that your UI labels are not perfectly synchronized with the GL vertices (they wobble very slightly due to independent sync). A minor detail, but once you have seen perfect GL sync, you cannot go back.

Comment: Youy could also use a particle system with a texture atlas, but that is significantly more complex, requiring shaders. It would solve the texture copy issue, though.